# AngularJs: Input value changes in display too using ng-model. I have tried ng-value and ng-bind too

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

```
 <div class="form-group">
                        Name <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="item" ng-model="shoppingItem.itemName" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        Image URL <input type="url" class="form-control" placeholder="item" ng-model="shoppingItem.imgUrl" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="save()" >Success</button>
                    </div>

app.controller('recipebookController',function($scope,$routeParams,RecipeService,$location){
    $scope.shoppingItems =RecipeService.shoppingItems;
    $scope.rp="Route parameter value"+RecipeService.shoppingItems[0].itemName;
    
    $scope.save = function(){
        RecipeService.save($scope.shoppingItem);
        $location.path("/");
    }
});

<div class="col-xs-12">
    <ul class="list-group">
         <li ng-repeat="item in shoppingItems"class="list-group-item text-center clearfix">
            <span style="font-weight:bold">{{item.itemName}}</span>
            <img ng-src="{{ item.imgUrl }}" width="40" height="40"/>`
         </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I enter save, the new data is saving row wise perfectly and displaying but when I re-enter new value into the input. The previously save value get changes as I type.

Comment: Can you please post a sample of the code? And tell us what you expect to happen?

Comment: @TheLeb yes provided brother

Comment: To confirm, the problem is that the value `item.itemName` changes as you type?

Comment: Yes it changes as I type

Comment: Then I believe the issue is you are binding the input to a control on the page rather than a property of a model. 

I'm a newbie but found this tutorial to be very helpful. If you have time, please consider following along:

https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: Thank you @TheLeb for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that you're facing is that when you call `RecipeService.save($scope.shoppingItem);`, the RecipeService is saving the *reference* to your scope variable.

So, instead of assigning the variable directly, I might try doing something like this:

`RecipeService.save(angular.copy($scope.shoppingItem));`

This will create a new copy of the object referenced by `$scope.shoppingItem` and will allow you to edit one of those objects without affecting the other.